# Change UI Bootstrap accordion group content by click a button in the previous group

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this accordion:

```
        <uib-accordion close-others="true">
            <uib-accordion-group heading="Action" is-open="true" class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group text-center" data-toggle="buttons" >
                    <button type="button" class="btn" 
                        ng-repeat="action in actions" ng-model="$parent.selectedAction" uib-btn-radio="action"
                        ng-class="{'btn-danger custom-btn-danger': $index == 0, 'btn-success custom-btn-success': $index == 1}" >
                        {{action.text}}
                    </button>
                </div>
                {{selectedAction}}
            </uib-accordion-group>
            <uib-accordion-group heading="Confirm" is-open="true">
                <div ng-if="selectedAction.value == 'reject'">
                    Comments
                    <br />
                    <textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <input type="button" value="Reject" class="btn btn-danger active" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="selectedAction.value == 'approve'">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom-btn-primary"
                                ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="$parent.selectedProcessLevel" uib-btn-radio="item"
                                ng-style="roundTopRight($index)">{{item.text}}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    Comments
                    <br />
                    <textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <input type="button" value="Approve" class="btn btn-success active" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </uib-accordion-group>
        </uib-accordion>
```

And this javascript:

```
$scope.selectedAction = { value: 'approve', text: 'Approve', isOpen: false };

$scope.actions = [
    { value: 'reject', text: 'Reject', isOpen: true },
    { value: 'approve', text: 'Approve', isOpen: false },
];

$scope.selectedProcessLevel = { value: '2lp', text: '2 Level Process' };

$scope.processLevels = [
    { value: '1', text: 'One' },
    { value: '2', text: 'Two' },
    { value: '3', text: 'Three' },
];

$scope.roundTopRight = function (index) {
    if (index == 0)
        return { 'border-top-right-radius': '4px' };
}
```

What I want to do is change the content of the second accordion Group by clicking the reject or approve button. Before using UI Bootstrap accordion it was a simble table and all worked perfectly.

Is there a scope issue?

And one more thing: what have I to do to collapse automatically the action group and expand the confirm group by clicking one of the buttons?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found a more simple solution: I used objects instead of primitives.
Here is the code: of the buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" 
    ng-repeat="action in actions" ng-model="selectedAction.value" uib-btn-radio="action.value"
    ng-class="{'btn-danger custom-btn-danger': $index == 0, 'btn-success custom-btn-success': $index == 1}" >
    {{action.text}}
</button>
```

And this is the ng-if:

```
<div ng-if="selectedAction.value == 'reject'">
```

And the javascript:

```
$scope.selectedAction = { value: '' };
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:  Here's a VERY simple example:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').service('AccordionService', function() {
  this.value = 'initial value';  
});
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function (AccordionService, $scope) {
  $scope.service = AccordionService;
});
```

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <uib-accordion close-others="false">
    <uib-accordion-group heading="First Accordion" is-open="true">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="service.value" />
    </uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="Second Accordion" is-open="true">
      Service value: {{ service.value || 'no value set' }}
    </uib-accordion-group>
  </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

To answer your first question, yes, there is a scoping issue.  In Angular, by default, nested scopes inherit and scoped fields are inherited for objects and copied for primitives (which is why you almost never want to use primitives).  However, this model breaks when you use isolate scope directives - which is what we are using in the `<accordion-group>` element - [here's the code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js#l66-L70).

But wait! All's not lost.  There's a few ways to solve this but the best would be to create a service that stores the values you need shared across accordion groups.  You can then reference those values anywhere in your app, including in other `<accordion-group>` elements.

The answer your second question is quite similar to the first - you need to toggle the value of `is-open` and the opening/closing will happen automatically.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers. I'm really new in Angular.  I created a service as you suggested following this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/)  `myApp.service('SharedValuesService', function () {  this.serviceSelectedAction = {}; } });` and this in my controller `$scope.selectedAction = SharedValuesService.serviceSelectedAction;` but it doesn't already work. I' sure that I'm doing wrong becouse in this way I think that I have the same scope issue. Is there any way to access directly to the service from markup without passing accross the controller?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a VERY simple example for you.  Be sure to include angular, angular-animate, angular ui bootstrap, and bootstrap CSS in your `<head>`.